# Problema con imprimir una lista

Tags: javascript, postgresql, lista, arraylist, wildfly

tengo un problema al hacer correr a una lista. En la base de datos tengo dos datos ingresados en diferentes fechas como se muestra en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realizo una consulta a la base de datos utilizando JDBC, y este resultado lo almaceno en una lista, para despues desplegarla.

Pero al momento de presentarlo en pantalla me lista solo un dato, dos veces.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al correrlo en debug veo que en la lista solo esta apuntando al primer dato

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como hago para que apunte a todos los datos que se encuentran dentro de la lista.

Añado el codigo que utilizo para la consulta en la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Para poder ayudarte debes mostrar un [mcve]. La imagen, aparte de pésima, no aporta nada para entender el problema. Agrega el código relevante en formato texto. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Por favor, lee atentamente [ask]. Coloca el código como texto no como imagen, para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.